# Add default class to Angular component

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to add a default class to an Angular component.
In my directive I load a template for this component. 
The directive is loaded by 'restrict: E' like so:

```
<my-angular-component></my-angular-component>
```

Result should be something like this:

```
<my-angular-component **class="my-angular-component"**>
    template
</my-angular-component>
```

Is there an angular method to add this specific class?

Comment: Please share your directive code

Comment: Directive link function write `element.addClass('my-angular-component');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use link for that see below example:

suppose this is ur **html** code:

```
<section ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <my-angular-component></my-angular-component>
</section>
```

**And this is Js file:**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MainCtrl($scope) {

}

//Directive that returns an element which adds buttons on click which show an alert on click
myApp.directive("myAngularComponent", function(){
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        template: "<span addbuttons >Click to add buttons</span>",
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs,$compile) {
           elem.addClass('myCss');
           $compile(element)(scope);

        }
    }
});
```

**Ans this is css:**

```
.myCss{
    background:green;
}
```

> Notice the link function used in the **directive**. It takes three
>   arguments: **scope,element,attributes**

### **scope**

– The scope passed to the directive. In this case it’s the same as the parent controller scope.

### **elem**

– The jQLite (a subset of jQuery) wrapped element on which the directive is applied. If you have included jQuery in the HTML before AngularJS is included, this becomes jQuery wrapped instead of jQLite. As the element is already wrapped with jQuery/jQLite, there is no need to again wrap it inside $() for DOM manipulations.

### **attrs**

– An object representing normalized attributes attached to the element on which the directive is applied. For example, you can attach attributes in HTML like:  and access it in the link function as attrs.someAttribute.

---

See example hear: http://jsfiddle.net/kevalbhatt18/vgpmoca3/1/